# loop over keys and add missing values

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary, key

I'm converting csv files into dictionaries, both csv files are similar but have different values. So one csv file has {name, state, website} and the other has {name, state, car}. The files have some of the same people in them so I want to loop over the keys and if they have the same name add the missing keys so for instance if both had a man named John Williams it would find that name and create a new dictionary saying {name: 'John Williams', state: 'FL", website "https://helpmeplease.com", car: "Kia"}. If there is a new person then I want it to create a new line and add it into the dict.

I have converted the csv files into dictionaries and I am comparing the key 'names' currently, I am stuck from here though and don't know where to go from here.

```
import csv
filename1 ="example.csv"
filename2 = "example2.csv"

blue = {}

with open(filename1, 'r', newline='') as f:
 for line in csv.DictReader(f):
    blue[line['name']] = line

with open(filename2, 'r', newline='') as h:
 for line in csv.DictReader(h):
    if line['name'] in blue.keys():
      #This is where I'm stuck
    else:
        blue[line['name']] = line
```

Comment: `fire[line['name']].update(line)`

Comment: You can also make this simpler by making `fire` a `defaultdict(dict)`; then you can just run through both CSVs and do `update` on all the entries instead of having to test whether they're already there.  I'll go ahead and post an answer showing how that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.update` to merge the contents of one dict into another.  I'd also use `defaultdict` to manage the dict of dicts, since then you can just merge data in without having to check whether the dict needs to be created first.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

filenames = ["example.csv", "example2.csv"]

fire = defaultdict(dict)  # type: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            fire[row['name']].update(row)
```

Note that if you have variables like `filename1` and `filename2` and copy+pasted code that does roughly the same thing to both/all of them, it's usually a good clue that you should be using a list and a `for` loop instead!  :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, I'm still pretty new in the world of programming I really appreciate the help